# How to show multi level nested data through datagridview in C# Windows application?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

I want to show *nth* level master detail data through a datagridview & C# in Windows application. Here I attached a picture where the master detail data is shown through grid. So please advice me how I can show data in this tree structure through datagridview in Windows apps with C#.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848637/Nested-DataGridView-in-windows-forms-csharp

Answer (score 1):

There is an [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx) at MSDN that describes how this can be achieved by extending the standard DataGridView.